# Python while loop to continue when inputting an integer. Break when inputting string or character

Tags: python, string, input, while-loop, integer

I am new to python and trying to figure out how to make this program **only** take a string or character and then have it spell out said string/character. Unfortunately, when using the lines `while word != str() or chr():
    word = input("Enter a string or character...")` I am constantly prompted to "Enter a string or character" even when I inputted a string/character to begin with. How would I be able to go about fixing this so that the program takes a string and breaks out of the while loop so that it can spell whatever I typed in?

```
word = input("What is your word? ")

while word != str() or chr():
    word = input("Enter a string or character...")

for char in word:
    print(char)
```

Comment: There are several problems here. None of them are really relevant, though, because `input` *always* returns a `str` object, so you don't need to check the type of `word`.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense now.

Comment: Have you done any research? There are plenty of helpful resources online for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
word = input("What is your word? ")

while type(word) is not str():
    word = input("Enter a string or character...")

for char in word:
    print(char)
```

Also, the input will always be a string.

If you want to check for numeric input, then you should do something like:

```
try:
    int(word)
except ValueError:
    # input is a string
else:
   continue  # input is a number
```

Comment: The check `while type(word) is not str():` will _always_ be `True`. `type(word)` in this case will always return `<class 'str'>` while `str()` will always return `''` (empty string). These two things will never be equal. What you're looking for is `while not isinstance(word, str):`, but again this will always be `True` because `input()` _always_ returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work:

```py
word = input("What is your word? ")

while word.isdigit(): # the word contains only digits
    word = input("Enter a string or character...")

for char in word:
    print(char)
```

Few notes:

1. In your code `word != str()` would hold true as long as your input is not empty, as `str()` is a (very ugly) way of initializing an empty string.
2. The return type from `input()` is str. If you want to treat it as an integer or any other type you'd have to cast/parse it